# Want to implement notification pattern role based

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, notifications, integration

I am developing a website in which I want to notify all/specific other users about a user's activity based on roles.

1- If a manager do add a user this activity shows to all users.
2- If a user add a client it will only show to this user or more specifically to its manager.
and so on.

I already read azure Service-Bus Queue,Topic and RabbitMQ.

These solutions are great but I want to implement my own.

Please suggest me a solution.
Note:  Notification/messaging is within the application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SignalR** is the solution which I used and it works great for me.
**SignalR** provide the easy and clean implementation for client to client communication through Server...